# CloudWatch Logs, Elasticsearch service expiration

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I'm using CloudWatch Logs streaming to Amazon Elasticsearch service (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_ES_Stream.html)

Currently, I've set Events expiration in Cloudwatch to 7 days for my Cloudwatch log group that is streaming to Elasticsearch. Is this going to take care of also cleaning up & expiring logs in Elasticsearch as well? I want to avoid running out of space in Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

No it will not.

Cloudwatch logs and elasticsearch (now migrated to Opensearch) are 2 different services.
You would need to put some cleaning mechanism for your elasticsearch cluster (for example a daily lambda)